# Unload a spring profile previously loaded

Tags: spring

I was wondering if there any chance to unload a spring profile previously loaded ?

I need to unload a profile based on external conditions.

thanks,
Jorge

Comment: By Spring Profile do you mean Spring Context?  Or do you want to swap from one Profile to another?

Comment: Each profile loads beans for 2 different functionalities (which actually they should be 2 different apps) in one web application and i would like to disable a profile at runtime (which will disable one of both functionalities)
Profiles are shown below:
[code]
<beans profile="app1">
        <import resource="app1-profile.xml" />
    </beans>

 <beans profile="app2">
        <import resource="app2-profile.xml" />
    </beans>
[/code]

Comment: This sounds more like a permissions use case. Permit access or not to resources based on roles and authorities. To me this sounds like a feature that should be handled differently, not with Spring context unloading beans.